# Is it possible to add custom RGB color when applying a color to a to an object via script in Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have this Script that I made to change the color to green when the pressure plate is triggered, So I am wondering if it's possible to use a custom RGB color in script instead of using a already set color like red, green, or blue.

here's the code I used to change the color:

```
PressurePlate.material.color = Color.green;
```

Comment: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Color-ctor.html ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `PressurePlate` is of type `MeshRenderer`

```cs
PressurePlate.material.color = Color.green;
```

If `PressurePlate` is of type `Renderer`

```cs
PressurePlate.material.SetColor("_Color", Color.green);
```

Color green in RGB is `rgb(0, 255, 0)`. If you want to set the opacity, then the color code is written as `rgba(0, 255, 0, 0.6)` (opacity is `0.6` in range `0` to `1` and `a` in `rgba` is alpha value). In unity, the `Color` takes in float values ranging from `0` to `1`. If you have a color code `rgb(255, 255, 0)`, in unity, it's `new Color(255/255f, 255/255f, 0/255f)`. You divide each color code with 255.

Assuming `PressurePlate` is of type `MeshRenderer`,

```cs
Color someColor = new Color(0f, 1f, 0f, 1.0f);
PressurePlate.material.color = someColor;
```

Comment: For some reason the code you shared is not setting the objects color to green. I am getting no errors as well.

here's the code:
`Color someColor = new Color(0f, 255f, 0f, 1.0f);
            PressurePlate.material.SetColor("_Color", someColor);`

Comment: @Miracle, does `PressurePlate.material.SetColor("_Color", Color.green);` work? What type is `PressurePlate`? I have edited my question accordingly, take a look at it

Comment: You're mixing value types, in color you use normalized values (0.0 - 1.0) and not 0-255.

Comment: @Shrimp, that's what I did, I used normalized values only

Comment: Could you tell us what kind of shader is used for the material? Is standard URP/HDRP shader?

Comment: Note that you wouldn't mix byte and float ... it is either `new Color(0f, 1f, 0f, 0.6f)` or `new Color32(0, 255, 0, 153)` in your example ;)

Comment: I asked @Miracle to change what he wrote in comment to normalized values, as in the comment he used 255. Then I asked about material/shader used if there actually is a _Color field in this shader.

Comment: also `If PressurePlate is of type MeshRenderer` .. i doesn't matter at all. `.material` is a property of `Renderer` and works the same for all types derived from it. Further note that `.color` is just a shortcut property for using `GetColor("_Color")` and `SetColor("_Color", someColor)` ... so your two examples are completely equivalent .. it depends on the used **shader** whether it has a property `_Color` or not

Comment: oh got it now, looks like i have some research to do on this topic

Comment: @Shrimp apologies, i misread the names and i thought you are OP

Comment: I am using the urp shaders. Sorry I took so long to reply I went to sleep.